# Parent - Child relation Child ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID {get;set;}
    /*...
    Some other properties
    ...*/
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> Details {get;set;}
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderID {get;set;}
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderDetailID {get;set;}
    /*...
    Some other properties
    ...*/

    public Order Order {get;set;}
}
```

I have also specified the relation in the OnModelCreation like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>().HasKey(detail => new { detail.OrderID, detail.OrderDetailID});
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>().HasOne(detail => detail.Order)
                                            .WithMany(order => order.Details)
                                            .HasForeignKey(detail => detail.OrderID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Everything works without any errors.
My problem is that in this case when I create an order with details the OrderDetailID is incremented for all the details and I am getting the below in the database.

```
OrderID OrderDetailID ....     
17      19              3   15.0000 15.0000 EA      
17      20              3   15.0000 15.0000 EA     
18      21              1   25.0000 0.0000  EA     
18      22              1   25.0000 0.0000  EA
```

I understand that the way OrderDetailID works is corresponding to the configuration in my code. But my problem is that I need to get the following picture in the database:

```
OrderID OrderDetailID ....     
17      1               3   15.0000 15.0000 EA     
17      2               3   15.0000 15.0000 EA     
18      1               1   25.0000 0.0000  EA     
18      2               1   25.0000 0.0000  EA
```

In other words I need the OrderDetailID to be reset to 1 for every new order.
I can't find any configuration option in Entity Framework to get this to work in the way that I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create a trigger in your database it should increment it on inserting

Comment: @DavidEdel how should the trigger determine whether to increment the value or to reset to 1?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long reviews I ended up adding the below script to the Migration.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [DetailLineNbr] ON Details AFTER INSERT AS 
                        BEGIN
                        declare @minLineNbr int;
                        declare @maxExistingLineNbr int;
                        SET @minLineNbr = (SELECT MIN(DetailID) FROM inserted);
                        SET @maxExistingLineNbr = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(LineNbr) FROM Details WHERE Details.OrderID in (select inserted.OrderID from inserted) AND Details.DetailID not in (select inserted.DetailID from inserted)),0);
                        UPDATE Details
                        SET LineNbr = Details.DetailID - @minLineNbr + @maxExistingLineNbr + 1
                        WHERE Details.OrderID in (select inserted.OrderID from inserted) AND Details.DetailID in (select inserted.DetailID from inserted) 
                        END");
```

The solution suggested by David Edel works only for single line inserts.
Unfortunately, in my case almost all inserts where multiple line inserts.

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting is called ***Identity column based on another column***. Neither SQL Server nor EF Core has default support for this.

You have to do it manually. In EF Core, you have to assign the property (column) value by getting the max value of this property (column) from database and then incrementing it by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no such thing as an autoIncrementing Id that can reset like that, it looks more like a behaviour that you should create within your code, maybe concider using the index in `Details` list as your OrderDetailID

Answer (score 0):

Best is if you can create a trigger in your database on insert

It should set the orderDetailId based on highest ID from that specific order

Example:

`SELECT ISNULL(MAX(OrderDetailID)+1,1)  FROM orderDetails WHERE orderID = inserted.OrderID`